T4 Template not able to generate response in json from helper method
I'm trying to generate a Json using T4 template by calling the helper method .
Helper method GetApiEndpointInfo() generates all the endpoints data by accessing a assembly.
Below is the helper class method
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Web.Http;

namespace Therapist.Tests.Unit.Helpers
{
    public class APIReflectionHelper
    {
 public static string GetApiEndpointInfo()
 {
     try { 
     var endpointInfoList = new List<ApiEndpointInfo>();
     var customTypes = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

     var externalAssembly = Assembly.Load("Therapist.Service");

     var controllers = externalAssembly.GetTypes()
         .Where(t => t.Namespace == "Therapist.Service.Api" && t.IsClass && t.Name.EndsWith("Controller")).OrderBy(t => t.Name);

     foreach (var controller in controllers)
     {
         var routePrefix = controller.GetCustomAttribute<RoutePrefixAttribute>()?.Prefix ?? string.Empty;

         foreach (var method in controller.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
         {
             var route = method.GetCustomAttribute<RouteAttribute>()?.Template;
             if (route == null)
             {
                 // Skip methods without a valid RouteAttribute
                 continue;
             }

             string httpType = string.Empty;
             if (method.GetCustomAttribute<HttpGetAttribute>() != null) httpType = "GET";
             else if (method.GetCustomAttribute<HttpPostAttribute>() != null) httpType = "POST";
             else if (method.GetCustomAttribute<HttpPutAttribute>() != null) httpType = "PUT";
             else if (method.GetCustomAttribute<HttpDeleteAttribute>() != null) httpType = "DELETE";

             if (httpType == string.Empty)
             {
                 // Skip methods without HTTP method attributes
                 continue;
             }

             // Get the API version from the custom attribute
             var apiVersionAttributes = method.GetCustomAttributes<MapToApiVersionAttribute>();
             var apiVersions = apiVersionAttributes.Any() ? apiVersionAttributes.Select(attr => attr.Versions.Single().ToString()).ToList() : new List<string> { "1.0" };

             // Check if the method is obsolete
             var obsolete = method.GetCustomAttribute<ObsoleteAttribute>() != null;

             // Get input parameters
             var inputParameters = GetMethodParameters(method, customTypes);

             // Get the return type
             var returnType = GetFriendlyTypeName(method.ReturnType);

             foreach (var apiVersion in apiVersions)
             {
                 // Create and add the endpoint info for each version
                 var endpointInfo = new ApiEndpointInfo
                 {
                     Route = $"{routePrefix}/{route}".Trim('/'),
                     HttpType = httpType,
                     ApiVersion = apiVersion,
                     Obsolete = obsolete,
                     InputParameters = inputParameters,
                     ReturnType = returnType
                 };

                 endpointInfoList.Add(endpointInfo);
             }
         }
     }

     var result = new
     {
         Endpoints = endpointInfoList,
         CustomTypes = customTypes
     };
     return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented);
     }
     catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
     {
         var loaderExceptions = ex.LoaderExceptions;
         foreach (var loaderException in loaderExceptions)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(loaderException.Message);
         }
         throw; // Re-throw the exception after logging
     }
 }}}

I'm calling the helper method from the T4Template file to get the response and generate the json file
**T4 template
**
<#@ template language="C#" debug="true" hostspecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".json" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ assembly name="Newtonsoft.Json" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Web.Http" #>

<#
    // Assembly Path for your project
    string assemblyPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile), @"C:\Clinicient\Mohawk\Therapist\Tests\Therapist.Tests.Unit\bin\Debug\Therapist.Tests.Unit.dll");

    // Attempt to load the assembly
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);

    // Get the type for APIReflectionHelper
    var type = assembly.GetType("Therapist.Tests.Unit.Helpers.APIReflectionHelper");

    // Get the method to invoke
    var method = type.GetMethod("GetApiEndpointInfo");

    // Invoke the method
    string json = (string)method.Invoke(null, null);

    // Define the output path relative to the project
    string outputPath = Path.Combine(Host.ResolvePath("Controller"), "ApiReflectionOutput.json");
    
    // Write the JSON output to the file
    File.WriteAllText(outputPath, json);
#>


I'm getting a loader exception saying "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
But the version of System.Web.Http installed is 5.2.3.0 (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3)
